# OOP structure, and possibly some stuff about threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, sdl

I'm programming a 2D game in SDL, and in this game, I want to create a 'bird' class, which will animate a simple bird on the screen. The way I've thought this would best work is by having a base class which draws stuff I want it to, then have subclasses ('bird' class, a 'player' class, and eventually classes for bullets, etc). The draw member function of the base class will call member functions of the subclasses to draw themselves (using functions from the base class), so firstly, is this a reasonable way to structure my game?

Secondly, when I call the draw function of, for example, my 'bird' class, the function needs to know which frame of the animation it's up to, and return the appropriate image. Would it be better to increment the frame number every time the function is called, or to have the function run on a separate thread, such that at any arbitrary time that the function is called it will return the correct frame, but this would mean I'd need a separate thread for every animated sprite on the screen.

The reason I'd consider doing the second, is that in the first method, different computers running the same program will run at different speeds, and hence so will the animation, so my only option would be to fix the number of times per second the render function is called. In the second method, with the frame counter running in a separate thread, I could set a specific time delay before the function is allowed to display the next frame, meaning the speed of the overall animation is totally unaffected by the number of times the render function is called.

One last quick question - for my 'bird' class, would it be better if each instance of the class is an individual bird, or have a single instance which controls X many birds? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask this type of question on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

But to answer your questions anyway, there are a LOT of ways you can structure it. For a small game, you'd likely be better off using some sort of basic OOP structure that tends toward *composition over inheritance*. ([wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and [an SO question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)).  That should give you some amount of flexibility and reusability and help ward off spaghetti.

Typically you want your frame updates to occur on the main thread. No need to completely obliterate determinism in a coding project that's already going to have elements of randomness to deal with! Although it is not unheard of to execute object updates across multiple threads, this is something you may want to hold off on until you absolutely need it.  Avoid [premature optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516160/planning-for-efficiency-early-vs-premature-optimization).

You'll want to look into timing mechanisms and managing FPS & game clock. There are accessible, simple techniques out there that don't require multi-threaded programming.

Another thing to think about is sometimes the game experience doesn't become more enjoyable just because your programming concepts are fancy. You might find that players get frustrated when animation and FPS slow downs don't sync up nicely with movement.

There are so many variables relating to efficiency of your game that it's hard to answer this - but these days I would less concerned about slow machines than I would be about first making a cool game with fun mechanics and *cool enough* graphics and shaders that it's visually stimulating without feeling like I need to compete with John Carmack.

> Secondly, when I call the draw function of, for example, my 'bird' class, the function needs to know which frame of the animation it's up to, and *return the appropriate image.*

This raises red flags to me. I may be assuming the worst, but rather than glossing over it let's talk about it. In a "game" with a small number of sprites, you could potentially get away with loading separate images into memory and displaying them as needed. But that can get ugly in a hurry as time goes by in development and you start to add objects to your application. For every image you want to display, the hardware (the thing that implements the whatever GL specification you're targeting) will need to reserve some memory for these images. Not a horrible thing in and of itself. The sticky, bottlenecky part of this is when the graphics hardware wants to actually draw stuff. It has to take what's sitting in general memory on the hardware and stick it in video memory. Hence, sprite sheets (or texture atlases) become very useful - rather than saying "hey draw this other image" you just say "hey draw a different part of the same big image" (and those different "parts" would be the frames of your animations; multiple animations can live inside a texture atlas; texture atlases are generally sized by powers of 2 which is optimal for the GPU).   [Side note on powers of 2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent).

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265808/420594):

> The holy rule of GPU programming is that less you talk to GPU, the more she loves you.

Of course you'd then need to balance this against managing shaders, but that's something you can look into and experiment with as you get into this.

Another avenue, which actually is like composition on crack, is an [Entity-Based Component System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). This allows you to add behaviors and properties to objects (like the ability to react to input commands from the controller/keyboard, or the ability to draw to the screen, or the ability to take damage or modify 'health' or be invincible, the ability to react to physics/gravity).

For a small game, I would advise you not to do that, unless you're treating this like a massive learning exercise.  But even then, it's probably a good idea to break some of these concepts into bite-sized chunks and approach them one game at a time.

I hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Cheers, that was a very helpful answer. Regarding the part about 'returning the appropriate image', I just meant returning the appropriate section of the sprite sheet.

Comment: And yes, I am intending to treat the creation of this game as a learning exercise - but obviously only to an extent, I'm not so eager to learn about mutexes and semaphores and all the finer details of multithreaded programs whilst I'm still getting the hang of properly structuring an object oriented programming. I'm also not in the slightest worried about optimisation at the moment either.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb is to have a container of things to animate.

Since objects have different animation rules, you may want to have an "animate" function and pass the object's location information (such a frame; x, y, and z ordinates, etc.).

Another view is to have the objects remember their location.  This may simplify the coding of the frame.  The frame would tell all the objects to animate, and the objects would change their position with the frame caring about their positions.

Comment: So in most cases it would be over complicating matters to introduce multiple threads?

Comment: You would have one thread that wakes up, checks the container and animates those objects that need animating, then goes back to sleep.